# Swagger not working inside Docker in .Net core project?

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core, swagger

net core Web API application. I have created swagger with Azure AD authentication. My swagger properly works when I am using IIS. When I run using docker I get This site can’t be reached. Below is my startup code.

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        azureActiveDirectoryOptions = configuration.GetSection("AzureAd").Get<AzureActiveDirectoryOptions>();
        swaggerUIOptions = configuration.GetSection("Swagger").Get<SwaggerUIOptions>();
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    private readonly AzureActiveDirectoryOptions azureActiveDirectoryOptions;
    private readonly SwaggerUIOptions swaggerUIOptions;
    //
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        services
           .AddAuthentication(o =>
           {
               o.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

           })
           .AddJwtBearer(o =>
           {
               o.Authority = azureActiveDirectoryOptions.Authority;

               o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
               {

                   ValidAudiences = new List<string>
                   {
                      azureActiveDirectoryOptions.AppIdUri,
                      azureActiveDirectoryOptions.ClientId
                   },
                   ValidateIssuer = true,
                   ValidateAudience = true,
                   ValidIssuer = "https://KmartAus.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/default",
                   RoleClaimType = ClaimTypes.Role
               };
           });

        services.AddMvc(options =>
        {

            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
            options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1); ;

        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });

            c.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OAuth2Scheme
            {
                Type = "oauth2",
                Flow = "implicit",
                AuthorizationUrl = swaggerUIOptions.AuthorizationUrl,
                TokenUrl = swaggerUIOptions.TokenUrl,
                Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    {"Read", "13269k8-a2ea-45a1-96e7-6580f57b6e30/.default" }
                }
            });
            c.AddSecurityRequirement(new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>
            {
                    { "oauth2", new[] { "readAccess", "writeAccess" } }
            });
        });


    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {

            c.OAuthClientId(swaggerUIOptions.ClientId);
            c.OAuthClientSecret(swaggerUIOptions.ClientSecret);
            c.OAuthRealm(azureActiveDirectoryOptions.ClientId);
            c.OAuthAppName("Swagger");
            //c.OAuthAdditionalQueryStringParams(new { resource = azureActiveDirectoryOptions.ClientId });
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
        });
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

Below is my docker file.

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://*:44319
EXPOSE 44319
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["LocationServicesAPI/LocationServicesAPI.csproj", "LocationServicesAPI/"]
RUN dotnet restore "LocationServicesAPI/LocationServicesAPI.csproj"

COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/LocationServicesAPI/


RUN dotnet build LocationServicesAPI.csproj -c Release -o /app

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "LocationServicesAPI.dll"]
```

When I hit run on Docker, http://localhost:54330/ starts in browser and If I hit http://localhost:54330/swagger/index.html nothing opens up. If I try to hit http://localhost:44319/swagger/index.html then also I am not able to open swagger. Below is my container port mapping whne I do docker ps.

> 44319/tcp, 0.0.0.0:54330->80/tcp
>   Below files exist inside the container.

```
Controllers  Dockerfile  LocationServicesAPI.csproj  LocationServicesAPI.csproj.user  Models  Program.cs  Properties  Startup.cs  appsettings.Development.json  appsettings.json  bin  obj  out  wwwroot
```

Can someone help me to figure it out the issue? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I can confirm swagger work in docker. I guess in docker it try to use https because of UseHsts.

Comment: Oops, seems UseHsts doesn't work as what I thought, never mind.

Comment: Seems that the dockerfile is incorrect, you build the project to /app directory but the WORKDIR is still in /src/LocationServicesAPI/, so there's no dll to run.

Comment: You also need to expose Port 80 , so add the line EXPOSE 80 in the dockerfile

Comment: Also I hope it is running in Kestrel if not then you need to host it in Kestrel within docker.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers but none of them worked for me

Answer (score 25):

Using the default configuration for ASP.NET Core, swagger only works in the development environment. Add the following environment variable to your Dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://*:44319

ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development #Add this line.

EXPOSE 44319
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["LocationServicesAPI/LocationServicesAPI.csproj", "LocationServicesAPI/"]
RUN dotnet restore "LocationServicesAPI/LocationServicesAPI.csproj"

COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/LocationServicesAPI/


RUN dotnet build LocationServicesAPI.csproj -c Release -o /app

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "LocationServicesAPI.dll"]
```

Comment: The above worked for me so long as you add it to the correct build and remove the comment that caused an error for me.

Comment: This might be the correct answer. It worked for me

Answer (score 6):

the swagger UI is accessible only in dev env by default so rather you  change the env to dev or you change the condition in app middelware so you take  the swagger middleware out of the condition

```
 if (env.IsDevelopment())
   {
     app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
     app.UseSwagger();
     app.UseSwaggerUI(c => 
     c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "myappname v1"));
    }
```

so it will become like this

```
if (env.IsDevelopment()) {...}
   app.UseSwagger();
   app.UseSwaggerUI(c => 
   c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json","myappname v1"));
```

Comment: I did that but still getting 404 while its working when i run project in dev environment

Comment: try to navigate to ip:port/swagger or show me your error screen

Comment: you need to set the env variable in docker-compose file , if you set it while using docker run sometimes it does not work ...

Answer (score 0):

I dealt with the same issue today, and I finally solved it. You can use the following file as an example.

Actually, what fixed it for me was adding this:

```
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
```

Here's the entire dockerfile :

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build WORKDIR /app

COPY ./*.csproj ./ RUN dotnet restore

COPY . .

RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS runtime WORKDIR /app COPY
--from=build /app/out ./

ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development

EXPOSE 80 

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ProjectName.dll"]
```

I hope it serves its purpose.

Comment: Try this URL to access Swagger: http://localhost:portnumber/swagger